# Are there any current, major phones based on Android 4.4 that don't have Google Chrome pre-installed as a browser?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android, stock-android

I'm asking since Android 4.4 doesn't include a browser and it needs to be licensed separately by the handset manufacturer.

Comment: Look at any 4.4 based phone that doesn't have Google Play Services.  Chances are that Chrome will not be pre-installed on such phones.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only concerned with a brief moment in time. Any answers which might be true now will quickly become out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly doubtful. If the phone is using Google Play Services, which every manufacturer must use and agree to a strict set of terms and conditions if they want their device to access the Google Play Store, then Chrome will be installed.

It's one of Google's key apps, along with Gmail, Maps and so on.